# Java inheritance : method not defined

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Pokemon{
private String _Name;
private String _Status;
private double _Hitpoint;
private int _Level;
private String _Type="General";
protected Pokemon(){
_Status="Alive";
_Hitpoint=50;
_Level=5;
}

protected Pokemon(double Hitpoint, int Lvl){
_Status="Alive";
_Name="Pokemon";
_Hitpoint=Hitpoint;
_Level=Lvl;
}

public String getStatus(){
 return Status
}
public String getName(){
 return _Name;
}

public double getHitpoint(){
 return _Hitpoint;
}

public int getLevel(){
 return _Level;
}

public abstract void makeNoise();

public abstract void dealDamage();
}
```

Above is the abstract parent class. Below is the child class:

```
public class Pikachu extends Pokemon{
String _Type="Electric Pokemon";
String _Name;
public Pikachu(){
 this("Pikachu",50,5);
}

public Pikachu(String Name,double _Hitpoint,int _Level){
 super(_Hitpoint,_Level);
_Name=Name;
}



 public void makeNoise(){
  System.out.println("Pika Pika");
 }

 public void dealDamage(){
  System.out.println(getName()+" uses Shockwave");
 }
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Pikachu Pika=Pikachu();
  Pika.makeNoise();
  Pika.dealDamage();
 }
 }
```

When I tried to run the code, an error occurred at the line:

```
Pikachu Pika=Pikachu();
Error: The method Pikachu() is undefined for the type Pikachu
```

Sorry if this question is very amateurish (I've just started to learn Java). Can anyone give me a simple explanation as to why my Pikachu is undefined while I have actually defined the method Pikachu previously?

Thank you

Comment: `Pikachu Pika = new Pikachu();` (note the new `new`).

Comment: Read up on how to use constructors. There's no use in trying inheritance before you understand that

Answer (score 3):

Constructor needs to be called with `new`

`Pikachu Pika = new Pikachu();`

Answer (score 0):

You need create a new instance of Pikachu, with the `new` keyword.

```
Pikachu Pika = new Pikachu();
```

Read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)